# Interesting search question: Find a value that's NOT in a list (Daily coding problem, May 26, 2020)

Tags: algorithm, groovy, big-o

### I was wondering if anyone would be willing to give me some feedback on my solution to today's question from the Daily Coding problem email list. It's an interesting question about finding the first value that's NOT present in a list, as opposed to finding a value that IS there.

This problem was asked by Stripe.

Given an array of integers, find the first missing positive integer in linear time and
constant space.
In other words, find the lowest positive integer that does not exist in the array.
The array can contain duplicates and negative numbers as well.

For example, the input [3, 4, -1, 1] should give 2. The input [1, 2, 0] should give 3.

### You can modify the input array in-place.

My main question is that I'm not sure if I've met the O(n) time and O(1) space requirements. Here is my solution using Groovy:

```
def find_first( Xs ) {
  ys = []
  szXs = Xs.size()
  // First, transfer Xs list to a set ys.
  szXs.times { // this loop is O(n)
    if ( (hd = Xs.head()) > 0 ) { ys << hd; } // We only need to keep val if it's positive.
    Xs = Xs.drop(1); // Remove val from Xs in order to meet O(1) space requirement.
  }
  ys = ys.toSet() // converting list to set is O(n)
  sz = ys.size()  // ys.size() might be same as Xs.size(), but it could be smaller, so give it a new var.
  for (int i = 1; i < sz; ++i) { // this loop is O(n)
    if ( !ys.contains(i) ) return i // Testing a hash set for set membership is O(1)
  }
  return sz + 1 // if this point is reached, ys had all values [1..sz] already
} // end find_first

def test(Xs) {
  println "\nstarting with Xs = " + Xs
  ans1 = find_first( Xs )
  println "first missing = " + ans1
}

xs1 = [ 3,4,-1,1 ]
xs2 = [ 1, 2, 0 ]
xs3 = [ 7, 8 ]
xs4 = [ 1,1,2,1 ]
xs5 = [ -4, -1 ]

test(xs1)
test(xs2)
test(xs3)
test(xs4)
```

### test(xs5)

And here is the output:

starting with Xs = [3, 4, -1, 1]
first missing = 2

starting with Xs = [1, 2, 0]
first missing = 3

starting with Xs = [7, 8]
first missing = 1

starting with Xs = [1, 1, 2, 1]
first missing = 3

starting with Xs = [-4, -1]
first missing = 1

---

So it's correct on that limited set of values, just want to be sure that it's O(n) time and O(1) space. Any advice is appreciated!
Hank

Comment: You could use a randomly generated number and check for it, make sure the random number is very large, it will prove very effective in solving...

Comment: Yes I was thinking about trying something like that. Generate lists of various slzes and profile them to see if the time is going up linearly. But then that wouldn't help me on the space question. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Btw, I had forgotten that I had seen this question before: it's the first problem given in the book "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design." They call it "The smallest free number" problem. It's a great book from the parts of it I've read so far, highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with groovy, but it seems like your code is `O(n)` space, since you create an additional hash set (`ys`).

Note that the question has a hint:

> You can modify the input array in-place.

This can be done in `O(n)` time with O(1) space, by first sorting the array inplace with [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), and then iterating over the values to find first missing one.

Comment: Yes it's nice to use radix sort due to its efficiency, thanks for the tip.